# Failed to access gmapping parameter

Tags: navigation, rosparam, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need help.
I'm trying to make map by using hokuyo_node and gmapping.
Although I can check constructing of a map by rviz, I can't access to any parameters of gmapping.
When I tried rosparam list, the following message is displayed:

> hoge@hoge:~$ rosparam list
> /hokuyo_node/allow_unsafe_settings
> /hokuyo_node/calibrate_time
> /hokuyo_node/cluster
> /hokuyo_node/frame_id
> /hokuyo_node/intensity
> /hokuyo_node/max_ang
> /hokuyo_node/max_ang_limit
> /hokuyo_node/max_range
> /hokuyo_node/min_ang
> /hokuyo_node/min_ang_limit
> /hokuyo_node/min_range
> /hokuyo_node/port /hokuyo_node/skip
> /hokuyo_node/time_offset /map_frame
> /rosdistro
> /roslaunch/uris/host_hoge__36584
> /roslaunch/uris/host_hoge__44203
> /rosparam/map_frame /rosversion
> /run_id /temporalUpdate

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37259/failed-to-access-gmapping-parameter/) by [s-kawakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/2637/s-kawakami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you just didn't set any parameters for gmapping. I guess you were not running it using a launch file but rosrun. Just running a node normally will not set anything on the parameter server, the node will just use the default values as documented at the [gmapping wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping). To actually set parameters, the most common way is to use a launch file. There are a few packages that contain launch files to start gmapping, e.g. in `pr2_navigation_slam` or in `turtlebot_navigation`.

You can create a file `gmapping.launch` and put the following content in it:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <rosparam>
      odom_frame: odom
      map_update_interval: 1.0
      maxUrange: 30.0
      maxRange: 60.0
      sigma: 0.05
      kernelSize: 1
      lstep: 0.05
      astep: 0.05
      iterations: 5
      lsigma: 0.075
      ogain: 3.0
      lskip: 0
      linearUpdate: 0.5
      angularUpdate: 0.436
      temporalUpdate: -1.0
      resampleThreshold: 0.5
      particles: 80
      xmin: -1.0
      ymin: -1.0
      xmax: 1.0
      ymax: 1.0
      delta: 0.025
      llsamplerange: 0.01
      llsamplestep: 0.01
      lasamplerange: 0.005
      lasamplestep: 0.005
      base_frame: base_link
    </rosparam>
    <remap from="/scan" to="/base_scan" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Have a look at the remap line at the end. You need to replace the topic `base_scan` by whatever topic your laser publishes to. If that happens to be `scan` you can just remove that line. Also, make sure that the `odom_frame` and the `base_frame` match your configuration.

Now you should be able to execute `roslaunch gmapping.launch`. After that call, the gmapping parameters should all be shown by `rosparam list`.

Note that `rosparam set` won't change anything for roslaunch or gmapping since roslaunch will overwrite the parameters again and gmapping parses them only when it's started up. If you want to change parameters, edit the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3